# Yotube video quality change using CSS media queries

Tags: css, iframe, video, youtube

I'm trying to use iframe embedding Youtube video on a responsive design webpage.
    How can I let the widest page comes with heigher resolution video
    (with parameter `&vq=hd1080` )?

Now I have the media query css scripts :

```css
@media screen and (min-width : 1000px) { 
    .video{width:700px; height:500px;} 
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width : 750px) { 
    .video{width:450px; height:300px; } 
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
    .video{width:260px; height:180px; } 
}
```

and the link :

```
<div class="video" style="float:left;">
    <iframe  type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx?version=3&rel=0" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Can I put different parameters for this link to each query?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use something like JavaScript for that. It's not a job for CSS.

However, there's a much easier way to resize those videos depending on your screen size. Let's say your videos always have the same width/height ratio, and let's say that ratio is 16:9. In that case, wrap an element around your video (a div or p, for example) and set it to

```
position: relative;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
overflow: hidden;
```

and the iframe inside it to

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

That way, the video will scale nicely at all screen widths.

If the video dimensions are likely to vary, there's a more complex method for this that involves some JS: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/

Comment: Thanks Ralph. May I use JS to select the HD youtube link for wider page, and select the normal quality one to the mobile page?

Comment: I would think you could use JS to gauge the viewport width and modify the URL based on that. But someone else will have to advise on how that could be done—and if it would even work. The problem is, someone might change the browser width while viewing the page, and that would make things tricky, I'd think. Anyhow, you don't know that someone on a wide screen wants the larger version. I'd say let the user decide (usually the best way).

Comment: Thank you~ You are so right, perhaps people don't want a larger video on wide screen. I tried make the video small and put the description to the right, it looks better and rich on the desktop mode.